# Overflow not showing up in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have 5-6 items in my **Action Bar**. When I set `ShowAsAction = "never"`, the items goes into the old styled menu which appears from bottom of the screen while I want the **three dot styled icon** to appear on **Action Bar**. Also when I click on it, the menu doesn't appear.

My menu file -

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item 
     android:id="@+id/About"
     android:title="About"
     android:orderInCategory="1"
     android:showAsAction="always"/>


<item 
    android:id="@+id/Settings"
    android:title="settings"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/item3"
    android:title="Item3"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/item4"
    android:title="Item3"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orderInCategory="4"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/item5"
    android:title="Item3"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orderInCategory="5"
    android:showAsAction="never"/>

<item 
    android:id="@+id/item6"
    android:title="Item3"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orderInCategory="6"
    android:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: You have a hard menu button on your device?

Comment: yes , I have hard menu button

Answer (score 11):

If you have a hard menu button on your device then the menu options that don't fit on the `ActionBar` will be placed on your device's menu button. If you have a newer device without this button then they will be placed in the overflow menu (the 3 vertical dots)

See [Creating an Options Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu)

I created a custom `layout` for a custom `ActionBar` so that I could have the same sort of look and functionality across all devices. You may consider doing the same thing if this is what you want.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry it couldn't be the answer you were probably looking for

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've been looking alot of time for a solution for this. I'm using android-sherlockBar. and I do have the menu button on my device. But as I can see from other apps, the 3 dotted menu is shown even though I do have this button.

Comment: @idish I'm not real familiar with the SherlockActionBar as I've never used it so you may be able to get what you want with that library. My understanding from reading what the author wrote about it is that it was only meant for a short-term solution which is why I decided to just create my own "Action Bar"

Answer (score 8):

Android disabled showing the overflow icon on devices which have physical menu button,
for some of you who still want it,here is a solution:

add this function to your activity:

```
private void forceShowActionBarOverflowMenu() {  
    try {  
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);  
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");  
        if (menuKeyField != null) {  
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);  
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);  
        }  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
}
```

and finally you add "forceShowActionBarOverflowMenu();" right after setContentView() in onCreate() in your activity.

Answer (score 5):

nest the menu as the following way and you will get the overflow icon and also the icon of in drop down if you specified.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_show_ir_list"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_friendslist"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText"
            android:title="List"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```